# .Private size discrepancies after rogue app filled disk with log and deleting file

Tags: encryption, disk-usage

Running Ubuntu 17:10, I am suddenly having the issue that my disk is running out of space.

I tracked it down to my `/var/log/syslog` growing rapidly for some reason (100s of GB),  but as system was being unresponsive, I deleted the syslog file (touched it to create it again).

Now, still having space issues.

Executing `df -h` I get:

```
daz@jupiter:~/.Private$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        3.2G  2.0M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  202G  191G     0 100% /
tmpfs                         16G  640M   16G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                    87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/loop1                    87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4830
/dev/loop2                    87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop3                   181M  181M     0 100% /snap/vlc/190
/dev/loop4                   198M  198M     0 100% /snap/vlc/365
/dev/nvme0n1p2               705M  188M  466M  29% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1               511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi
```

Executing `du -h --max-depth=1 ~/.Private` I get:

```
daz@jupiter:~/.Private$ du -h --max-depth=1
8.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6bym6kSm0Q5KNTKCf5dAbNk--
4.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6pCdwwELVs9P3Sh1.XlHWHU--
42M ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6PU1jOge6a0ELYNru.4ZX3k--
140K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6z7GWviGfGNNMQ3xHA5tCnk--
56K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6Z0NMwhE0-O-zpSEPdaghS---
35M ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6wQskGc4-3HMRhNxNZpc1bE--
32K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6yLjP.CtdfFYLmiLuV-fbA---
28K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-60TAaJFeZhOU5QVPAUIbM5k--
336K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6W4apvFS2aT1NyNizh5RXEE--
4.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6FppXVBJRclgrGoTs99ztEk--
28K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6wBE0bL0CK0UNNKoUiIB4cU--
100K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6bMjyVYxIa9okddryfmFcu---
180K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6FOc8G5CZJ9NfnM7hlwveKk--
564K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6uRG.Badk2JO1fdDw4K2oHE--
4.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-65BsIY1T.dxf6a2ovysdQAk--
63M ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6cWeD23sADoiBI.nDlGqNDU--
16K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6pCyBxwBxpUmvbzhxG0u7fU--
1.4G    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6VLIxgPprQ.vMvKCD5iqByk--
60K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-62E5xcrmhQzeXz8aJB5uTO---
1.1M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6ZaRts8Cf9i47vosUaCpAfU--
355M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6nrc5tcgFx2S4rR8CObokTU--
12G ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-64N2KbOqdQ90zAHcmOH9-8---
1.8M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6tDRLY7vvF3JqgR28gBYYyk--
396K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6gsAf6ITi306v4SgwFk-iPU--
648K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-62yPDQPlgCSV-mfKfXijGEE--
53M ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6QlTw.U-0ls7b-LY716SYW---
28K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6MedV1K8atphupU9pUALoXE--
16K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6xWDdx1Fi41HWEpvZmusRQ---
216K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6wVblo5C3GyIRpZF.2RC3sU--
4.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6OnpF0MChycXSM0GlwT2H9E--
4.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FXYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6vGYhpSzzvtLAmGDHADarV0TJKg4ns0HJVaZf9N-kHn--
40K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6WpbleJUieRGBbgMUn-wW9---
2.9M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6QaENDg3NoJ-0JG61-ShCG---
865M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-65W0.P8RDZmfBWBbVKvBqbU--
4.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6iSQDlxa6xxIDkV9SI5DuuU--
96K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-64YDw15WK6SDnjpCu7dzwRU--
546M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6u2KGQ6-IFPxGvdQhTJZhGU--
1.4M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6G6m64b-OMeN83JdBaFzWxU--
154M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6yh3UJjd.2yQuMrW79XM.pk--
1.8G    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6MLAmaM4om.rHu.x9HMvgoE--
14G ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6ZH11tb01kLZmI11rNVnnAk--
33M ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6vbP0kMp8RNKdSVkWWfufqE--
825M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6pk02my9u84NlhP8c4Wynjk--
52K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-67fxYqxzHhSRm68UwfhTNq---
204M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-61CDwaDPoQY7Aoz.06Fa1t---
13M ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-68MMwHOv3EmUdVfwZgXQHFk--
196K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-67AvKReqkCApAYTZ7hWTrHE--
2.6G    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6se0RgYJd4a3Mlr0VXHLKqU--
4.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6dTLE9TcYVlnBKJoziuD.NU--
228K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6un9YL2tfcCiuCaprW6xHkk--
3.6M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6UyBWtgnmD4ppftreaQgJVk--
240K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6AFSDWnskG3EoZeUDny3qjk--
4.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6dHReZFy-UfLu9J0W66.7jk--
919M    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-65OpYywD4XzT75VMWpEIGIU--
5.9G    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6-lurZ5yY7EgPynDoEB9k7---
57M ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6zuAa1HctuxG9GVqfM3qHiE--
29M ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6EG.mCwOr3D4jmgM0UYVCOk--
2.4G    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-67mLPTLX04xtLgH63y7dMEE--
28K ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FXYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6YvxVLeyLhg5fLmeoXRdN53XtPc8r9aGYmo-.kTfmCIQ-
4.0K    ./ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYQiTJmOpqUFUSNWmRh00t6pnQlSpAP5w-6UrVtB7Fhwsu3XIij9x9.DU--
```

Any advice?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, but as Ubuntu 17.10 is now EOL, take the opportunity to consider making a backup and installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @guiverc yup, this might be the impetus to do so!